# Linux USB gadget with functionfs: reading endpoint 1 not successful

Tags: c, linux, embedded, usb, embedded-linux

I want to use a iMX7-SOM as a vendor specific device (gadget) on a Windows10-PC with WINUSB driver. I'm using a Angstrom-based, Yocto-made image with Kernel v4.9.166.

I configured the gadget with libusbgx, mounted the functionfs at /ffs and wrote the decriptors to /ffs/ep0. The device is enumerated as expected and I get the commands on endpoint 0 (like "BIND", "ENABLE", "DISABLE" etc.).

So long so good...

On receiving "ENABLE" at endpoint 0 I want to open /ffs/ep1 and use poll() to read incoming data. But poll() is returning immediately and read() never returns (only when I plug out the device). On host side no application is running.

I used select() instead but the result was exactly the same.

When I use ioctl(fd_of_ep_1, FUNCTIONFS_FIFO_STATUS) I get the error message "Operation not supported".

```
int fd = open("/ffs/ep1", O_RDWR);

fd_set read_set;
FD_ZERO(&read_set);
FD_SET(fd, &read_set);

int ret = select(fd + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (ret < 0)
{
    perror("select");
}
else if (FD_ISSET(fd, &read_set))
{
    int foo = ioctl(fd, FUNCTIONFS_FIFO_STATUS);
    if (foo < 0)    perror("ioctl");
    else            fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", foo);

    char buffer[1024];
    if (read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) < 0)
    {
        perror("ep read");
    }
}
```

I expected that the select/poll functions will return when I open my application and the endpoint will be written by the host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer by myself:

It seems that only endpoint 0 (ep0) supports the poll function.

When you look at the supported operations of ep0 ([link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.2/source/drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_fs.c#L627)) you can find that 'poll' has a handler. In contrast the other endpoints (epX) don't have a similar function ([link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.2/source/drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_fs.c#L1061)).

Therefore poll() for epX set the flag POLLIN and returns immediately ([link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.2/source/fs/select.c#L750)).

Comment: Does it mean you need to poll ep0and when pollin is returned read from the right epX?

Comment: No, ep0 is the [control endpoint](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml#Control). When you poll it and it returns, you can read a _struct usb_functionfs_event_ (defined in linux/usb/functionfs.h).

Examples for handling these events: [int handle_ffs_ep0(usb_gadget * ctx)](https://github.com/viveris/uMTP-Responder/blob/master/src/usb_gadget.c) or [static int read_control(void)](https://github.com/projectara/gbsim/blob/master/functionfs.c).

For the epX I use a simple, blocking read which I interrupt by a signal.